# como poner icono en la barra de tareas a una aplicación empaquetada con cx_frezee

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

Buenas tardes como puedo, cambiar el icono por default de una aplición empaquetada con cx_frezee:

este es mi setup.py

dentro del QtDesigner añadi el icono a cada ventana tambien pero no cambia nadda.

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
build_op={
    "packages":['os','idna','requests'],
    "include_files":[
        'Inicio.py',
        'Login.py',
        'Busqueda.py',
        'Traspasos.py',
        'add_users.py',
        'Registro.ui',
        'Login.ui',
        'Inicio.ui',
        'Venta.ui',
        'Consulta.ui',
        'Traspasos.ui',
        'add_Users.ui',
        'Registro.py',
        'Firebase_load.py',
        'Inventario.py',
        'Sqlite.py',
        'Users.db'

    ]
}
setup(
    name = "xe",
    version = "1.1",
    description = "df",
    executables =[Executable("Login.py",base = "Win32GUI",icon = 'icono.ico')],
    options ={"build_exe":build_op}
)
```

esta es la imagen que aparece en la barra de tareas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Con cz_freeze ni idea, pero con pyinstaller yo he sido capaz de asignar el icono. Dale un intento.

Comment: @Saelyth, como le hiciste con pyinstaller

Comment: Simplemente: `os.system("pyinstaller --noconsole --icon=appicon.ico --onefile source/my_project_main_window.py")`